# How to set bar-chart hover to show x axis' labels?

Tags: python, bokeh

I have generated a simple bar chart. In order to make it more interactive, I have added Hovertool into the graph.

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file
from bokeh.models.glyphs import HBar
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Legend, HoverTool
output_notebook()

# Set x and y
functions = ['func_1', 'func_2', 'func_3']
percentage = [233.14, 312.03, 234.00]

# Set data source (color needs to be set precisely with len(category))
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(functions=functions, percentage=percentage))

# Set the x_range to the list of categories above
p = figure(x_range=functions, plot_height=600, plot_width=800, title="The Overall Use of my functions",
          x_axis_label='Functions', y_axis_label='Percentage')

# Categorical values can also be used as coordinates
p.vbar(x='functions', top='percentage', width=0.9, source=source)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=[('Percentage', "@percentage")]))

show(p)
```

Although it shows a value from y axis correctly, I would like to display a label from x axis instead (e.g., Func1: 9.45). Just like the picture that is shown from the link (I cannot post an image yet):

https://i.ibb.co/235jR39/Untitled.png

**Update#1**
I tried to come up with something, this is what I got:

```
# Set Hover
percentage = list(map(lambda i: str(i), percentage))
my_hover = list(zip(functions, percentage))
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips=my_hover))
```

It turns out it shows every detail in every bar as shown below

https://i.ibb.co/72hmD8q/Untitled-2.png

Comment: Is your data for **functions** a list with values or with tuples? (btw: please always post a minimal but **runnable** code) Could you add a small (representative) part of that data to your example?

Comment: @Tony Basically, it would look like this functions = ['func_1', 'func_2',.....n]
percentage = [123, 342, .....n]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for Bokeh v1.0.4.

```
import math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.palettes import Category10

df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.rand(10, 1), columns = ['percentage'], index = ['Func {}'.format(nmb) for nmb in range(10)])
df['color'] = Category10[10]

source = ColumnDataSource(data = dict(functions = df.index.values, percentage = df['percentage'].values, color = df['color'].values))

p = figure(x_range = df.index.values, plot_height = 600, plot_width = 800, title = "The Overall Use of my functions",
           x_axis_label = 'functions', y_axis_label = 'percentage')

p.vbar(x = 'functions', top = 'percentage', width = 0.9, color = 'color', source = source)
p.add_tools(HoverTool(tooltips = '<font color=blue>@functions:</font><font color=red> @percentage</font>'))

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = math.pi / 4  # Rotate axis' labels

show(p)
```

Result:

[image]